# Make R Markdown output accessible

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-markdown, accessibility, alt

I'd like to output an accessible version of a presentation I'm making with R Markdown ioslides. At this point, I've been struggling to find much documentation on alt-text for dynamically generated images - **not pointers to images** - there's lots of information available online on that front.

Seems like the easiest thing to do might be to output my document as a word_document instead of a presentation, and ensure that figures have captions, using fig.cap argument in the chunk header.

However, I'd like the captions to be available *only* as alt-text - so that this document doesn't look strange to folks who aren't using screen reader tech (I'd like to make my alt-text nice and descriptive, but for folks who can see ok, this will seem odd, because the graph will do the talking instead).

I've included a reprex below. How can I still include the fig.cap as alt-text in the output word document, but not have it show up underneath the graph?

Also, if you are aware of any good resources on making RMarkdown docs accessible, I am all ears!!

Thanks for your help.

````
---
title: 'test doc'
author: "Nova"
date: "April 2020"
output: 
  word_document:
  fig_height: 5
fig_width: 10
height: 500
widescreen: yes
width: 500
---

```{r setup and comments, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE,
                      message = F,
                      warning = F,
                      fig.height = 5,
                      fig.width = 10,
                      fig.cap = NA)

library(ggplot2)
```

## cars
```{r ggplot, include=T, fig.cap = "this is some alternative text about this figure"}
ggplot(cars)
```
````

Answer (score 2):

I'd go back to some kind of HTML output, because it's simpler.

If you want ioslides output, you can use  `fig.cap="Some alt text"` in the chunk option to set the alt text for the figure.  Unfortunately, this also generates a visible caption, but you can suppress that.  For one slide, just insert inline CSS:

```
<style>
    .caption {
        display:none;
    }
</style>
```

somewhere on the slide before the figure.  To do it for the whole presentation, put that text in a .css file and include it with YAML like

```
output: 
  ioslides_presentation:
    css: style.css
```

It's probably also possible to change the template for this output style, but that looks like a lot more work.

Comment: Thanks. I'm thinking that I might actually prefer the word output, because then I can tweak (easily) the last few things that might not make it through an accessibility checker. I'm a little afraid that it would take me days to figure out all the tweaks in an html doc. Plus, I'm exporting plotly graphs in the html version (static in word), and they have "links that go nowhere" in accessibility checkers.